# Creating a function in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to create a function in SQL Server

I created a temp table but I want to create function in sqlserver for this below code

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME
       ,@EndDate DATETIME;

SELECT 
    @StartDate ='20100101',
    @EndDate = GETDATE()
      --convert(varchar(8), GETDATE(),112); 

;With DT_TempTbl as
(
   SELECT 
       @StartDate AS YearMonth

   UNION ALL

   SELECT 
       DATEADD(MONTH, 1, YearMonth) 
   FROM 
       DT_TempTbl
   WHERE 
       YearMonth <= @EndDate
)
SELECT
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), YearMonth, 112) AS YearMonth1 
FROM 
    DT_TempTbl 
ORDER BY
    YearMonth1
```

Please help me to creating function in sqlserver

Comment: [Here's the official, complete MSDN documentation on `CREATE FUNCTION`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx), and [here's a great article about SQL Server function at Simple-Talk](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/sql-server-functions-the-basics/)

Comment: What is the problem with the code you have? Just put `CREATE FUNCTION` around it as per doco